# SwiftUI .toolbar ToolbarItem Custom Button Designs

Tags: swiftui, toolbar

Is it even possible to style a button when using the new .toolbar/ToolbarItem code?

This is a simple example of adding a red background.  Nothing.

```
 ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        
      Button(action: {}) {
          Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
          .background(.red)
       }
                         
 }
```

Previously I would just add this to add a background, color, size, shadow, circle, etc...

```
 .buttonStyle(NavButtonStyle())
```

Am I wasting my time?  The last thing I want are the ugly blue images. I want to customize them.

Thanks.

Comment: ToolbarItem is already a button so you don't need to use Button explicity. Make a view as normal without a button and add a gesture if you want to perform some action.

Comment: what about the styling?  or the action? i dont see how this would work?  thanks.

Comment: for styling, we can create a normal view like body view and for action if you want to redirect other screen use navigation link else add tap gesture.

Comment: Or use ```navigationBarItems(leading``` insted of ToolbarItem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why this works - but it does.  Would love to know if there is a better way?

I could not format the Image in any way - until I added the Text("").

I added the HStack just to be organized.

if you put the Text("") in front it moves the images over - so it is better at the end.

Good luck.

```
.toolbar {
    
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
       
        Button(action: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {
             
            HStack {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                .frame(width: 24, height: 24) 
                .background(
                     Circle()
                        .fill(Color.red) 
                )
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 3, x: 2, y: 2)
            
                Text("") // without this text the image formatting will not show
                 
            }

        }
       
    }
```